# Tomcat cannot find the jsp page I'm trying to forward to

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I'm building an application and currently working on my login page. When I launch Tomcat it starts up fine and opens a browser which displays my index.jsp page to log in. However on successful log in I am not forwarded to the next jsp page as instructed in the login servlet, instead I get a 404 "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

I have checked the web.xml I which looks fine, I'm using annotations to map servlets. I dont know what else to try. Even if I deliberately enter incorrect log in details I receive the same error rather than the output contained in the "else" statement.

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String uname = request.getParameter("username");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("password");

        if (uname.equals("MyUsername") && pwd.equals("MyPassword")){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }else {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write("User details not recognised");
        }


    }

}
```

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you forward to `/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp`, the server looks for a file `welcome.jsp` inside a directory `WEB-INF` in your context root, that is the `WEB-INF` directory.

So, you should not forward to `/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp`, but to `/welcome.jsp`.

Anyway, `WEB-INF` is reserved and does not work, no matter where you redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried just using "/welcome.jsp", that doesnt work. When I've used servlets in the past I've always used the relative path and its worked fine. Even when I'm not forwarding to that jsp page by entering incorrect user details, I should hit my "else" statement however I still get the 404.

Comment: Is `welcome.jsp` located in the same directory as `index.jsp`?

Comment: I think tomcat does not allow requests to `WEB-INF`.

Comment: welcome.jsp is not in the same directory as index.jsp, if I put index.jsp into the WEB-INF directory I get the 404. If I take welcome.jsp out of the WEB-INF directory and leave it where index.jsp is, nothing changes

Comment: The `WEB-INF` directory is reserved. Put `welcome.jsp` out of it and try to access if from the browser/curl/http(s).

Comment: That worked!! I can now hit the jsp from the browser, why cant I forward it from my servlet? I'll paste the xml below for reference:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>

Comment: What if you forward to `welcome.jsp` or `/welcome.jsp`? (Try both)

Comment: I have but no joy. I'm concerned that it wont display the output in the else statement also, that issue makes me think its not the forwarding thats the problem, I shouldn't get a 404 when I'm trying to print output to that page.

Comment: Yes, numerous times

Comment: Can you forward to `index.jsp`?

Comment: index.jsp opens in the browser with no issues when tomcat starts up. This is where I have my login form